# Missing required param id vue y docker

Tags: nodejs, typescript, vue.js, docker, vue-router

Resulta que estoy dockerizando una app de vue creada utilizando vite. Y al momento de ejecutar la aplicacion en localhost me aparece "Missing required param id" y no renderiza los elementos de la web

```
FROM node:18-alpine as deps
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install

FROM node:18-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM node:18-alpine as runner
WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install -g serve
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY --from=builder /app/dist ./dist

CMD [ "npm", "run", "serve" ]
```

ese el dockerfile que estoy utilizando para compilar la app. Al hacer estos mismos paso en mi pc sin usar docker, la aplicacion se ejecuta sin problema